# ncc build with module type

Tags: javascript, node.js, build

i'm trying to build my `index.js` in a single contained file to remove necessity of a `package.json` and just run `node index.js` to work. I'm using `@vercel/ncc` to do this, that's working very well with `commonjs`, but when i try to build with module type, when i run the code it doesn't work.

I run the command:

```
ncc build index.js -m
```

This is my test code:

```js
import { createLogger, format as _format, transports as _transports } from 'winston';

const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: _format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
        //
        // - Write all logs with importance level of `error` or less to `error.log`
        // - Write all logs with importance level of `info` or less to `combined.log`
        //
        new _transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
        new _transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
    ],
});

//
// If we're not in production then log to the `console` with the format:
// `${info.level}: ${info.message} JSON.stringify({ ...rest }) `
//
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.add(new _transports.Console({
        format: _format.simple(),
    }));
}
```

This is my `package.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "typescript-test-2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@vercel/ncc": "^0.36.1",
        "winston": "^3.10.0"
    }
}
```

Then, when i run `node dist/index.js` it throws this error:

```
file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14506
module.exports = require("util");
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at 3837 (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14506:1)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14546:42)
    at 5825 (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:41:12)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14546:42)
    at 1251 (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:770:14)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14546:42)
    at 3605 (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:5264:16)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14546:42)
    at 7829 (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:5695:23)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/app/scripts/dist/index.js:14546:42)
```

Can someone help-me please?

Comment: @Abubakr, i've updated de NCC library version and it worked, but i don't know the exactly reason why.